# How to run "another Makefile"?

Tags: c, makefile

I have two Makefiles under one directory. One is called "Makefile", another is called "Makefile.coverage". However, "make" can only execute the "Makefile". How can I execute what's in "Makefile.coverage"?

Comment: `make -f Makefile.coverage`

Answer (score 2):

From the [make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Makefile-Arguments):

> The way to specify the name of the makefile is with the ‘-f’ or ‘--file’ option (‘--makefile’ also works). For example, ‘-f altmake’ says to use the file altmake as the makefile.

So in your example it would be

```
make -f Makefile.coverage
```